# Adding markers to a map.jade file(leaflet) using node.js & mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug, leaflet

```
exports.Markermap = function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('markers');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,results){
        res.render('markermap', {
            "list" : results,
            vlat : req.params.lat,
            vlon : req.params.lon
        });
    });
};
```

this is the node.js file and it is rendered onto a jade file using a for/each loop but doesn't work

```
html
    head
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css')
    body
        h1#title GIS Framework B4048270
        #map(style='height: 700px;')
            script(src='http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js')
            script.
                var map = L.map("map").setView([#{vlat},#{vlon}], 13);
                L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'}).addTo(map);
            each results,i in list
                var marker = L.marker([#{results.lat},#{results.lon}]).addTo(map);
```

but without the loop the jade file works perfectly

```
 html
        head
            link(rel='stylesheet', href='http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css')
        body
            h1#title GIS Framework B4048270
            #map(style='height: 700px;')
            script(src='http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js')
            script.
                var map = L.map("map").setView([#{vlat},#{vlon}], 13);
                L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'}).addTo(map);
                var marker = L.marker([#{list[0].lat},#{list[0].lon}]).addTo(map);
```

Each time i try new indentations or change the loop 'Cannot read property' errors occur, please looking forward to your reply

Answer (score 0):

Everything after the script. is literally emitted into your html and jade constructs will not work there. You can use a regular javascript for loop to iterate over the list. You will also need to JSON.parse the various fields if they are not primitives because interpolation wouldn't work either with in the script tag.

Comment: thanyou. any suggestions how to implement the javascript loop?